# Doctrine DBAL sql logger in test environment

Tags: doctrine

I want to check my query time using `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger` while testing.

Config in config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'
        logging:  true
        profiling: true
```

Code:

```
public function testSingleInsertTime()
{
    $maxTimeInMs = 0.1; // Please ignore this and the fact that I'm testing single insert. Actual code is different.

    $em = static::$entityManager;
    $em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new DebugStack());

    /** @var DebugStack */
    $sqlLogger = $em->getConfiguration()->getSQLLogger();

    $productState = (new ProductState())
        ->setId(123)
        ->setHash('EXP000276669cc123038419f265bf124')
    ;

    $em->persist($productState);
    $em->flush();

    dump($sqlLogger->queries);die; // HERE i get an empty array :(

    $actualTime = 1; // TODO: get from logger

    $this->assertGreaterThan($maxTimeInMs, $actualTime);
}
```

After `php bin/phpunit --filter testSingleInsertTime tests/Doctrine/ProductTest.php` I'm getting an empty array after flush is called. What is wrong?

__

**UPDATE**

Look, even simple controller with `dev` environment  is failing!
Something is wrong with my code.
Sql logger might work in the other way.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack;

class DataDMLController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/action", name="action")
     */
    public function action(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new DebugStack());

        /** @var DebugStack */
        $sqlLogger = $em->getConfiguration()->getSQLLogger();

        $productState = (new ProductState())
            ->setId(124)
            ->setHash('EXP000276669cc123038419f265bf124')
        ;

        $em->persist($productState);
        $em->flush();

        dump($sqlLogger->queries); // an empty array!
        die;
        
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the DebugStack's code. Your test configuration looks OK

Comment: I just use Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack class.
I updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that to get configuration from connection (not directly from entity manager).

`$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new DebugStack());`

We have to understand that EntityManagerInterface has it's own configuration and Connection has it's own as well so we have 2 different configurations and we have to set sql logger for a connection which is in DBAL component and such component manages executing queries. Well that's not the role of entity manager so now it's clear and understandable.

__

Options

```
logging:  true
profiling: true
```

are not required.